# Generic javadoc command that always generates all javadocs in a given tree?

Tags: java, command-line, javadoc

When I have to generate javadocs for a new, unfamiliar project, I find that I spend a long time trying to simply write the correct command, specifying all the packages, all the source trees, etc. It's time-consuming and error-prone: I'm probably missing some source.

So let's say I have a directory myproj, and underneath it there are a few packages (and various other resources and stuff), and under those package directories there are eventually some src/ directories, and then lots of my/awesome/java/project/package type structures.

Is there a single command that will always recurse over EVERYTHING and generate ALL javadocs in one output location? I don't care how long it takes. Something brain-dead like `javadoc -d doc -sourcepath . -subpackages *` would be great. Failing that, what's the easiest way to generate all javadocs, no matter what the directory structure is?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `find` to find all Java source files and then send them to `javadoc`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" | xargs javadoc -d outputdir
```

Comment: For extra marks, a command that works on XP? (That was very lame of me not to mention it.) Will MKS it if not possible otherwise.

Comment: better throw some memory arguments in there to be sure:

find . -type f -name "*.java" | xargs javadoc -d outputdir -J-ms39m -J-mx40m

Comment: It works. But if you want to add media in your javadoc, it won't.

Answer (score 22):

On Windows you can do it like this:

Generate file list:

```
dir /s /b *.java > file.lst
```

Generate javadoc:

```
javadoc -d outputdir @file.lst
```

Comment: Excellent, native, functionally equivalent alternative to the above.

Comment: Is there a way to get Javadoc to generate the index list of all packages after using this method.  with the simple "javadoc -d [dir] @[file]" method there is no index.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work if some of the paths have spaces in the name?

Comment: @RyanLundy Encapsulate all of them inside a single/double quote. For example: dir "/s dir" "/b dir" *.java > file.lst ; javadoc -d "outpit dir" "@file.lst"