# Is there a online Javadoc for the Phonegap Android API?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm searching for the Javadoc of the Phonegap Android API, for the classes like DroidGap and the others in the phonegapp jar.

I didn't find it on the Phonegap site or wiki.

Is there an online version of this documentation ? Is this part of the [support](http://www.phonegap.com/support) ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try building them yourself.

I downloaded the [source from GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android), extracted it, and then at the command line did:

```
javadoc -d docs -sourcepath framework/src/ com.phonegap
```

I did this from within the folder where the files were extracted.

docs/ is the name of the new folder it created, in there is an index.html I was able to launch int he browser.

Comment: It's working of course. I uploaded the doc on my site : http://raphael-lemaire.com/phonegapjavadocs/index.html

Comment: Ok, apparently the link above is a casualty of the move from PhoneGap to Cordova. It was actually pretty painful to get a URL to the Apache Cordova git repo, but here it is:


https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-cordova-android.git

Once I got that, I just wanted to generate Javadocs for the full source tree, but apparently *that* is painful as well. Here's the magic answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709692/generic-javadoc-command-that-always-generates-all-javadocs-in-a-given-tree

Comment: And to follow up on Scott's comment, the actual git clone URL is https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-cordova-android.git

Comment: None of the links in the answer or any of the comments work apart from the one linking to another SO question. Where to get the sources?

Answer (score -2):

Follow the bellow link.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/index.html

This link consist of the API references for the PhoneGap.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the Javascript API, and I'm searching for the Java API.