# How to generate docs for our code like javadocs?

Tags: java, notepad++, javadoc

I commit code documentation is very essential to maintain the software product. I am using notepad++ to write the java code. I installed one of its plugin NppDocIt that inserts auto comments by pressing `ctrl+alt+shift+D`. Its good to know about methods but I want to generate code documents like java docs for example [This Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

**Update-1**
Thanks for good guidance and I learned a lot.

I tried to generate javadoc as following:

```
F:\Java\Tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes>javadoc -d "C:/docs" -sourcepath -package "com/i18n/source/i18n" -subpackages com
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "com/i18n/source/i18n"
1 error
```

My package resides as:

```
com
  |--i18n
       |--resources
            |--bundles
                  |--labelsBundle
```

Please advise where I am wrong?

**Update-2**
**Answer:**

1. I added all java files in one folder
2. Created one folder for example c:/docs
3. run this command from commandline `javadoc -d "C:/docs" *.java`

   and successfully my codes documentation generated

Thanks from the bottom of my heart to stackoverflow and participants of this thread

Comment: Why on earth do you use notepad++ for programming in a language like Java? You should use an IDE, like Eclipse or Netbeans. These have functions that generate JavaDoc (can also be done from command line with 'javadoc'). Have you tried googling 'how to generate JavaDoc'?

Comment: `javadoc` is a tool that scans the java source for comments in order to create the html documentation (like you've linked). if you are already writing valid javadoc style comments, you just need to run the utility: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html

Comment: I agree that it might be irrelevant to this question. However, as the OP mentions that code documentation is essential for code maintenance, so is the usage of an IDE. Have fun maintaining (refactoring, debugging) code with a text editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate Javadoc from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592396/how-to-generate-javadoc-from-command-line)

Comment: Vote up for javadoc generator tool link

Comment: Vote up for generating docs via command line

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question here: [Generic javadoc command that always generates all javadocs in a given tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709692/generic-javadoc-command-that-always-generates-all-javadocs-in-a-given-tree)

From [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4946061/266531) from user [stian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17542/stian),

> On Windows you can do it like this:
>
> Generate file list:
>
> `dir /s /b *.java > file.lst`
>
> Generate javadoc:
>
> `javadoc -d outputdir @file.lst`